# Array parameter in a powershell function does not load the first element

Tags: arrays, function, powershell, parameters

I have a function that takes one string parameter, and one array of string parameter

```
Function w
{
    param([string]$format, [string[]]$args)
    Write-Host $format
    Write-Host $args
}
```

Then I execute the function in the following way:

```
w "formatParam" "args1" "args2"
w "formatParam" "args1" "args2" "args3"
w "formatParam" "args1" "args2" "args3" "args4"
w "formatParam" "args1" "args2" "args3" "args4" "args5"
```

As can be seen in the output, the string array does not seem to load the first parameter, that is meant to go into the array:

```
formatParam
args2
formatParam
args2 args3
formatParam
args2 args3 args4
formatParam
args2 args3 args4 args5
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

#### $args is Special

`$args` is already a special variable in powershell; you shouldn't be declaring it as a parameter because you're overriding it. Let's name it something else, like `$remaining`.

#### Arrays use commas

The way you're passing the arguments in (with spaces) makes them look like different parameters. To pass an array you'd have to call it like this:

```powershell
w "formatParam" "args1" "args2","args3","args4","args5"
```

with commas. Since that's likely not what you want, you need to rewrite the function.

#### Remaining arguments

```powershell
Function w
{
    param(
        [string]$format, 
        [Parameter(
            ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true
        )            
        [string[]]
        $remaining
    )
    Write-Host $format
    Write-Host $remaining
}
```

And now you should be able to call it like so:

```powershell
w "formatParam" "args1" "args2" "args3" "args4" "args5"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the name of your parameter, "args". `$Args` is an automatic variable, so shouldn't be used outside its purpose. From [`Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113212):

> Contains an array of the undeclared parameters and/or parameter
>   values that are passed to a function, script, or script block.
>   When you create a function, you can declare the parameters by using the
>   `param` keyword or by adding a comma-separated list of parameters in
>   parentheses after the function name.

If you change the name of your parameter, and then add commas between the arguments of your second parameter so that it is an actual array, it will work.